# LuaLaTeX: alphabet, number font picked from secondary font

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode-math

I am looking forward to achieve alphabet, numbers as the same font used inside `\rmfamily`, `\sffamily`, `\ttfamily` environments. At present, alphabet & number fonts are picked up from Mathfont which needs to be picked from its font family.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\def\mathtest{$A09Z [α β θ τ ε χ] [\alpha\beta\theta\tau\epsilon]$}

\begin{document}

abc \mathtest 

\bgroup\sffamily def \mathtest\egroup

\bgroup\ttfamily ghi \mathtest\egroup

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Any suggestions.

Comment: Fonts in math mode don't follow the font directives made outside math mode.

Comment: Is there a way to direct fonts for alphabets and number inside math to pick the requested one. Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to select whatever style you need for math eg a sans serif digit via `\symsf{2}`  math does not use the same fonts as text so the text font switches have no effect on math/